# validating data I have on a website is correct compared to what I have on a data base

Tags: java, validation, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation, browser-automation

Here is what I am trying to do: scrape a website with bunch of table and compare the values with what I have on a database. Example
say that I have the table below and I wanna compare it with what have in ms sql.

[image]

what tools can I use to do this? is it a good idea to do this kind of validation test as part of functional or ui automation test ? I am using java and testNG. when does this kind of validation happen, if ever?  I can't find any example of this on the internet.

I tried making jdbc connection in my test suit to query the data and then scraping the site and storing the data in array list then comparing the values. it worked, but now the tables are getting bigger and it is becoming more complicated and convoluted. so I am wondering if there is another way of doing this.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: if the table has the usual html table structure, i.e. `<table><thead><tr><th>...</tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>...</tr></tbody></table>`, then I suggest using selenium with python, because then all you have to do is to is `pandas.read_html(htmltable.get_attribute('outerHTML'))` where `htmltable = driver.find_element(xpath)` and you get a handy table like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4lRJ.png) which you can easily export to csv or other formats